# Reversing a bash for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have this:

```
for (( count= "$WP_RANGE_START"; count< "$WP_RANGE_STOP"+1; count=count+1 ));
```

Where `WP_RANGE_START`is a number like 1 and `WP_RANGE_STOP`is a number like 10.

Right now this will step though going 1,2,...10

How can I do so that it counts backwards?(10,9,...1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the mirror image of what you have would be

```
for (( count="$WP_RANGE_STOP"; count >= "$WP_RANGE_START"; count=count-1 ));
```

But a less cumbersome way to write it would be

```
for (( count=WP_RANGE_STOP; count >= WP_RANGE_START; count-- ));
```

The `$` is unnecessary in arithmetic context.

When dealing with literals, bash has a range expansion feature using brace expansion:

```
for i in {0..10}; # or {10..0} or what have you
```

But it's cumbersome to use with variables, as the brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. It's usually easier to use arithmetic for loops in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your incrementing code can be "simplified" as:

```
for count in $(eval echo {$WP_RANGE_START..$WP_RANGE_STOP});
```

So, to decrement you can just reverse the parameters"

```
for count in $(eval echo {$WP_RANGE_STOP..$WP_RANGE_START});
```

Assuming you've got a bash version of 3 or higher, you can specify an increment or decrement by appending it to the range, like so:

```
CHANGE=1
for count in $(eval echo {$WP_RANGE_STOP..$WP_RANGE_START..$CHANGE});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is your problem.

```
i=11 ; until [ $((i=i-1)) -lt 1 ] ; do echo $i ; done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

You don't need any bashisms at all.